# preventDefault not working: whenever I click the bottom tabs the window jumps to the top

Tags: jquery, html

I have two tabbed navigation that work in synchrony.
But whenever I click the bottom tabs the window jumps to the top. I don't know if it's the fact that they are using the same class name.

HTML:

```
<!-- TOP TAB  -->
<section id="registerTabsContainer">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href=".tabViewer">Are you a Viewer?</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tabBusiness">Are you a Business?</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tabPlatform">Are you a Platform?</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- TOP CONTENT  -->
    <div class="registerTabsContent tabViewer">
        <h1>Register as a Viewer</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="registerTabsContent tabBusiness">
        <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="registerTabsContent tabPlatform">
        <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- BOTTOM  TAB  -->
    <section id="tourSummaryTabsContainer">

        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href=".tabViewer">Are you a Viewer?</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabBusiness">Are you a Business?</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabPlatform">Are you a Platform?</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- BOTTOM  CONTENT  -->
        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabViewer">
            <h1> Viewer content Bottom</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabBusiness">
            <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabPlatform">
            <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// tabs  script
$('li:eq(0) a', '.tabs').addClass('active');
$('.registerTabsContent:not(:first), .tourSummaryTabsContent:not(:first)').hide();

$('.tabs li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        var i = $(this).parent().index();
        $('li:eq(' + i + ') a', '.tabs').addClass('active');

        $('.registerTabsContent, .tourSummaryTabsContent').hide();
        var t = $(this).attr('href');
        $(t).fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Strange href you are using. Maybe you could use data-href instead of href

Comment: No error in the JS console ? It's like you're having a syntax error that break your script.

Comment: Can you recreate this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: works in fiddle on chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/6kCvu/1/

Comment: what browser are you testing with?

Comment: The problem he encounters is not resolved in this fiddle. If you reduce your windows, in order to make the result window scroll, you'll see that clicking on the links makes the document scroll to top, even with e.preventDefault(); and return false;. That's his question.

Comment: Without testing on my end, I believe it is scrolling to the top because you remove the content and the page size because small so it moves up. Than you show the other section and the scroll stays up top. To see if this is true, move the showing line above the hide() line and just call show() instead of fade. Does it jump?

Comment: If buy the 'content being removed' you mean the fade in and out of the content, then how can i fix this? How can the page stay in same place?  anyone knows a work around this please?

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug on Ubuntu 13.04 in either firefox or chrome.

Comment: I tested in FF, Safari and Chrome. All do the same. Page jumps up. :(

Comment: @epascarello It works man! By just removing the fadeIn it works. You were right. Even if I add the "slow" for the show, the same hapens.   it jumps to the top. I guess I will have to live without the fading in for now until there is a better solution. Thank to you all.